# Why does the space bar duplicate the previous field in creating mail merge labels instead of making a space?

Tags: ms-word, windows-10, label, mailmerge

I'm creating a Word mail merge label sheet. When I click on the field identification I want to insert into the label doc (eg First Name) and then hit the space bar to separate it from the next field (Last Name) instead of leaving a space the First Name field is duplicated. New to mail merge, but following online video instruction and they don't have this problem. What am I doing wrong?

avoid space bar, but no separation then between first and last names on final label.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.